# Template initialization:

Tags: c++, templates, matrix, vector, alias

I want to create row vector and column vector alias from Matrix class. How can I do that?

```
template<class T, unsigned int m, unsigned int n>
class Matrix {
public:
    Matrix();
        
    .
    .
    .

private:
    unsigned int rows;
    unsigned int cols;
    .
};
```

I get error here. I see that type alias for templates cannot be done. Is there any way I can handle it? For below I get error as "Partial specialization of alias template".

```
template<class T, unsigned int m, unsigned int n>
using rowVector<T,n> = Matrix<T,1,n>;

template<class T, unsigned int m, unsigned int n>
using colVector<T,m> = Matrix<T,m,1>;
```

Any pointers how can I achieve this?

Comment: please include the error verbatim in the question

Answer (score 3):

This is the correct syntax:

```
template <class T, unsigned int n>
using rowVector = Matrix<T, 1, n>;

template <class T, unsigned int m>
using colVector = Matrix<T, m, 1>;
```

Comment: Thank You. :) Do you recommend any good resource where I can learn templates and some special topics such as operator overloading in templates as well as combination with inheritance.

Comment: @Prajwal_7 [C++ Primer 5th edition](https://www.amazon.com/Primer-5th-Stanley-B-Lippman/dp/0321714113) is a great book that has chapters about the topics you mentioned. I highly recommend that book to anyone who is learning C++.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you must have more code than what you posted, because this

```
template<class T, unsigned int m, unsigned int n>
class Matrix {};

template<class T, unsigned int m, unsigned int n>
using rowVector<T,n> = Matrix<T,1,n>;

template<class T, unsigned int m, unsigned int n>
using colVector<T,m> = Matrix<T,m,1>;
```

Causes the following error

```
prog.cc:5:16: error: expected '=' before '<' token
 using rowVector<T,n> = Matrix<T,1,n>;
                ^
prog.cc:5:16: error: expected type-specifier before '<' token
prog.cc:8:16: error: expected '=' before '<' token
 using colVector<T,m> = Matrix<T,m,1>;
                ^
prog.cc:8:16: error: expected type-specifier before '<' token
```

The correct syntax for an [alias template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) is:

> ```
> template < template-parameter-list >
> using identifier attr(optional) = type-id ;
> ```

So the fix is

```
template<class T, unsigned int m, unsigned int n>
using rowVector = Matrix<T,1,n>;

template<class T, unsigned int m, unsigned int n>
using colVector = Matrix<T,m,1>;
```

And I suppose you want to remove `m` as parameter of `rowVector` and `n` as parameter of `colVector`:

```
template<class T, unsigned int n>
using rowVector = Matrix<T,1,n>;

template<class T, unsigned int m>
using colVector = Matrix<T,m,1>;
```

Comment: Thank You. Maybe I have put my question wrongly. I already have a matrix class defined. Matrix<T,m,n>, Now I want to use two special cases i.e, row-vector and column vector. In main function I want to intialize. For ex: rowVector<int,,2> should be equivalent to : Matrix<int, 1,2> automatically. I want to achieve this.. How can I do that?

Comment: @Prajwal_7 see my answer. `rowVector<int, 2>` is equivalent to `Matrix<int, 1, 2>` and `colVector<int, 2>` is equivalent to `Matrix<int, 2, 1>`.